# Java Robot simulating clicking at random spots but not moving properly

Tags: java

I am attempting to move the cursor to a randomly generated point. The point is calculated and then added to the coordinates taken in as the parameters. I only want the cursor to move down and to the right, which I do by adding the abs value of the random numbers to x and y. The cursor is then supposed to move to this new location and click. My issue is that the cursor does not exactly go to this new location and click, but will sometimes go to an unwanted spot and then execute a click. Is my random generation off? Or is there another reason as to why the cursor moves where it shouldn't?

```
public static void randClick(int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randX = -100;
    int randY = -100;
    int max = 10;
    int min = -10;
    int dev = 3;

    while (!(randX <= max && randX >= min)) {

        randX = (int) Math.round(rand.nextGaussian() * dev);
    }
    while (!(randY <= max && randY >= min)) {

        randY = (int) Math.round(rand.nextGaussian() * dev);
    }



    System.out.println("randX: " + randX + "randY: " + randY);
    System.out.println("xCoord + Math.abs(randX): " + (xCoord + Math.abs(randX))
        + " yCoord + Math.abs(randY): " + (yCoord + Math.abs(randY)));

    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove((xCoord + Math.abs(randX)), (yCoord + Math.abs(randY)));

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "Clicking Randomly" Is that not the point of the program you describe above?

Comment: It's clicking randomly because you're sending it to a random location (assuming `randX` is produced from some RNG). // You need to better explain your goal and provide more code for use to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: Edited for a clearer question. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I had what sounds like a similar problem recently with a Robot I made that was supposed to simply perform point & click actions. I would give it an X and Y value to move to, and it would be off on both the X and Y axes by varying amounts each time. I'm not sure what causes this (perhaps a bug in the class?), but I did come up with a way to deal with it.

My solution was to call the `robot.mouseMove(X, Y)` method multiple times in a row with the same coordinates. To test this, I put huge delays in between the `mouseMove()` methods and watched the pointer on the screen. It actually bounced back and forth around the desired position and inevitably settled into the actual coordinates I wanted. I know this isn't the prettiest solution, but it fixed my problem.

So in your case, you could do this in your `try` block:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
int newXCoord = xCoord + Math.abs(randX);
int newYCoord = yCoord + Math.abs(randY);
robot.mouseMove(newXCoord, newYCoord);
robot.mouseMove(newXCoord, newYCoord);
robot.mouseMove(newXCoord, newYCoord);
robot.mouseMove(newXCoord, newYCoord);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

You might not need to call it four times, but I found that to be a "magic number" that never failed.

Comment: I just tested it and this does in fact solve my issue, thanks

Comment: @BenWahner - Happy to hear my solution worked for you. Please be sure to [mark this answer as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) so that your question no longer appears unanswered. Thank you!